# Self Hosted mysql server on azure vm hangs on select where DB is ~100mb

Tags: mysql

I i'm doing select from 3 joined tables on MySql server 5.6 running on azure instance with inno_db set to 2GB. I used to have 14GB ram and 2core server and I just doubled ram and cores hoping this will result positive on my select but it didn't happen.

My 3 tables I'm doing select from are 90mb,15mb and 3mb.
I believe I don't do anything crazy in my request where I select few booleans however i'm seeing this select is hangind the server pretty bad and I can't get my data. I do see traffic increasing to like 500MB/s via Mysql workbench but can't figure out what to do with this.

Is there anything I can do to get my sql queries working? I don't mind to wait for 5 minutes to get that data, but i need to figure out how to get it.

==================== UPDATE ===============================
I was able to get it done via cloning the table that is 90 mb and forfilling it with filtered original table. It ended up to be ~15mb, then I just did select all 3 tables joining then via ids. So now request completes in 1/10 of a second.

What did I do wrong in the first place? I feel like there is a way to increase some sizes of some packets to get such queries to work? Any suggestions on what shall I google?

Just FYI, my select query looked like this

```
SELECT 
text_field1,
text_field2,
text_field3 ,..
text_field12
FROM
db.major_links,db.businesses, db.emails
where bool1=1
and bool2=1
and text_field is not null or text_field!=''
and db.businesses.major_id=major_links.id
and db.businesses.id=emails.biz_id;
```

So bool1,2 and textfield i'm filtering are the filds from that 90mb table

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be a bit late, but I have some suggestions.

First take a look the max_allowed_packet in your my.ini file. This is usually found here in Windows:
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6

This controls the packet size, and usually causes errors in large queries  if it isn't set correctly. I have mine set to 100M

Here is some documentation for you:

[Official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/packet-too-large.html)

In addition I've slow queries when there are a lot of items in the where statement and here you have several.  Make sure you have indexes and compound indexes on the values in your where clause especially related to the joins.